# WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha11 not working on API <= 22 when app closes from app list

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am downloading an mp3 file from this [URL](https://alquran.technobdapis.com/quranallaudio/arabic_with_bangla/arbn_002.mp3) using `HttpURLConnection` in `doWork` override method.

**Now the problem is download get killed when the app closes from app list in below 22 API devices.**

**Although upper versions of 22 API devices can restart download after closing the app from app list.**

I have searched for the solution but didn't find anything related to this. Although there has a question about `PeriodicWorkRequest` but that doesn't help me.

Have you any idea? Why does it happening?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: WorkManager implements job scheduling using JobScheduler on devices with API level 21+. For older devices it has the option to use Firebase JobDispatcher (if available) or Alarm Manager. Could you please add information about the device (OS version and manufacturer)? And please explain how you're closing the app in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

OS Version 5.1.1, Manufacturer: Samsung Galaxy J2, 
I am closing the app using `Overview button(Recent Button)` by swiping left or right.

Comment: Are you doing any custom configuration of the WorkManager?  When and how are you queuing these workers?

Comment: Here is my worker class - https://pastebin.com/WFz9h2D0

Starting the work from here - https://pastebin.com/eyJEDd3n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which device you are testing on. On some devices Swipe right from recents is treated as a force-stop. So all Alarms, and Jobs are cancelled. At that point the only thing `WorkManager` can do is to reschedule work when the application starts up again.

Comment: That was true. 
Thanks @Rahul